# NSTimer doesn't work in sleep mode?

Tags: iphone

In my App, i have set the timer for 3, 10 and 15 mins,but it goes to sleep mode and the audio doesn't ring.And after a long time it starts vibrating.Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer does not work in deep sleep mode, but you can make app awake by applying idleTimerDisabled property to TRUE, but remember, if you use this, battery will be utilized more....

Answer (score 2):

To save battery and resources, not all apps can run in the background, so when the device goes to sleep, your app might not be killed, but it does stop executing.

You can use UILocalNotifications to play the sound you want even if your app is not running.

Comment: Even though the App is in sleep mode it is still vibrating,but not at the exact time and even it doesn't play the sound.